# How to write Xpath.

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using this site - https://www.blueshieldca.com/home - and click on 'Find a Provider'. In  the `Located Near` input I am typing 'los' and I have to select the second value from suggested options.

Can any one please tell me how to write xpath for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach would be with explicit wait.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item'][2]"))).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this //li[@class='ui-menu-item'][@role='menuitem'] [2]

Answer (score 0):

You site is not working. please post the HTML and try with this:

```
//Select option last activity as Completed
            WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.name("status"));
            List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
            for(WebElement option : options){
                if(option.getText().equals("Confirmed")) {
                    option.click();
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: <ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1005; top: 659px; left: 370px; display: none; width: 270px;">
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
<a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Los Alamitos Junction, Orange, CA</a>
</li> In this I have to choose the value from drop down

Comment: //li[@class='ui-menu-item'][@role='menuitem']
use this xPath for selecting 2nd value.

Comment: Use this //li[@class='ui-menu-item'][@role='menuitem'] [2]

Answer (score 0):

I have most of it working. The problem I faced here is that it is not selecting the second value from the drop down..

```
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.blueshieldca.com/home");
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'primary_navigation_area')]//li[4]//a[contains(@onclick,'dcsMultiTrack')]")).Click();
        IWebElement entercity = driver.FindElement(By.Id("location"));
        entercity.Click();
        entercity.SendKeys("los");
        wait.Until((d)=>driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item'][@role='menuitem'][2]")));
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item'][@role='menuitem'][2]")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("findNow")).Click();
```

Comment: new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item'][5]"))).click();